# Confusing mealtimes

Tags: meaning, books

In "Great Expectations" by Charles Dickens, when Pip returns after his meeting with the escaped convict, how come it says that he had dinner right afterwards? Did he skip lunch? Or did his meeting take all day? Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quote to clarify the question for people who have not read the book? It could be difficult to determine what you're asking without explanation of what occurs in the book. Including the time at which the meeting with the escaped convict occurs would be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original meaning of *[dinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinner)* was a noon meal (the most significant meal of the day).

In most dialects it now means the evening meal, but some folks still refer to the noon meal as *[dinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinner)* and the evening meal as *[supper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supper)*.

Comment: I remember reading (but don't have a reference) that it became fashionable among the upper crust to have dinner later and later in the day, eventually necessitating a light luncheon to stave off hunger pangs during the wait. The middle and lower crusts later followed suit.